# Basic age asker program in C++

Tags: c++

I used to do a little programming in c++, but I haven't for a while, and just recently started again. I decided to write a basic program to see where I'm at, as far as knowledge of the language. The program i wrote asks for the user's age, take's the input, and then has 3 options to choose from based on the user's input. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int age;
cout << "Please enter your age\n";
cin >> age;
bool error = false;
while (error = false)
{
    if (age > 105)
    {
        cout << "You're Too Old\n";
        continue;
    }
    else if (age < 1)
    {
        cout << "You haven't been born yet!\n";
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        error = true;
        continue;
    }
}
cout << "Your age is: " << age << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

My problem comes when I do enter an age that's outside of the range of 1-105. For some reason, it skips the entire if statement and just runs the code at the bottom. If someone could help me with this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It's funny because the whole `while (error = false)` thing wouldn't be present if it was just `while (!error)`, which is generally regarded as better than explicitly comparing booleans against true or false.

Answer (score 6):

To properly handle errors, I'd suggest

```
int age;
bool error = false;
do
{
    cout << "Please enter your age\n";
    error = true;

    if (!(cin >> age))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input\n";
        cin.clear();
        // skip rest of line to avoid numerous spurious errors on 
        // non-numerical input:
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

        if (!cin.good())
            break;
    } else if (age > 105)
    {
        cout << "You're Too Old\n";
    }
    else if (age < 1)
    {
        cout << "You haven't been born yet!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        error = false;
    }
} while (error);
```

Note

- This also treats stream errors (e.g. bad input like `whoops`)
- it *actually* reads the input again, if there was an error

See it **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3459955bd2905b73201e6528ca468ac2-46908b44a13fd97d96dc5f34139b69aa)** with the following input:

```
332
-9
0
whoops
flargle blasted furnace
22
```

Printing:

> `Please enter your age` **332**
>   
> `You're Too Old`
>   
> `Please enter your age` **-9**
>   
> `You haven't been born yet!`
>   
> `Please enter your age` **0**
>   
> `You haven't been born yet!`
>   
> `Please enter your age` **whoops**
>   
> `Invalid input`
>   
> `Please enter your age` **flargle blasted furnace**
>   
> `Invalid input`
>   
> `Please enter your age` **22**
>   
> `Your age is: 22`

Comment: What does `1<<22ul` mean?

Comment: @NeilKirk, It's a left shift. For the precise best number, `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` should be used.

Comment: It means: a very big number @NeilKirk. I guess INT_MAX or `std::numeric_limits<std::istream::stream_pos_type>::max()` would be in order

Comment: @NeilKirk: `1<<22ul` is ~`2097152` not `23`.

Comment: @NeilKirk Because it just needs to be a very large number. Honestly, INT_MAX is poor C++ style and `numeric_limits` is gonna be more confusing. Will edit to something simpler

Comment: Why not `1<<23ul` or any other random number? I don't understand what is confusing about my question.

Comment: @sehe I don't know if you care, but this mishandles both bad streams and EOF.

Comment: Another magic number is no less confusing. According to the website everyone hates (http://www.cplusplus.com) it should be `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`

Comment: @NeilKirk thanks for looking it up for me :) Now tell me, once more, how is this less confusing?

Comment: @MooingDuck somewhat fixed (it will do a 'moot' iteration after first EOF though. I don't particularly care about that for this instant. It's `std::cin` specific)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's confusing, it's correct. You could put a comment that it clears anything left over in the stream.

Comment: I've added a comment to clarify

Answer (score 1):

This loop is never executed: `while (error = false)`

It's equivalent to `while(false)`, because it sets error equal to false and then doesn't execute the loop.

It should say `while(error == false)`

As people have pointed out the input is not inside the loop so you'll see an infinite loop after you make the above fix. I think the bug will be obvious at that point -- the message will be repeated forever.

Comment: The code will go into an infinite loop even if you fix that error.

Comment: this will cause the "you're too old" text to appear in an infinite loop though